# Monorepo on Heroku getting "bash: node: command not found" error

Tags: heroku

I have a monorepo for which I am trying to deploy a package on Heroku. I have set up the buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile and added the PROCFILE config.

My procfile has the following type:

```
web: node index.js
```

When my app starts I get the error:

```
bash: node: command not found
```

I've tried adding the node buildpack in addition to the multi-procfile but that doesn't work either.